# wordpress creating a form with some different features

Tags: wordpress, for-loop

I have a simple question. What is the best way to create a form like this one http://www.condoroyalty.com/book-a-tour with the same features?

I can do it myself but what is the best way to integrate it? Develop the form under template, creating a plugin or...

I have another way, to use plugins but the plugins won't let me edit that form and I couldn't add the calendar.

Please give me some tips or a link.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

use JQuery, here some links:
http://www.queness.com/post/204/25-jquery-plugins-that-enhance-and-beautify-html-form-elements
http://www.jformer.com/
http://www.designyourway.net/blog/resources/55-jquery-form-plugins-to-download-and-use/

Good luck!